# Правильно присвоить значение переменной в pdo php

Tags: php, pdo

Такой код работает.

```
 ...

 $se = $conn->query("SELECT ... ;");
 $se ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $n = 1;


 while($row = $se->fetch()) {

    $x=$x.'"'.$n++.'":"'.$row[p1].'","'.$n++.'":"'.$row[p2].'",';


    $c1 = $row[c1];
    $c2 = $row[c2];
    $c3 = $row[c3];
 }

 ...
```

Select возвращает таблицу, в которой колонки c1, c2, c3 всегда имеют одинаковые значения.
Если я правильно понял, то в цикле формируется переменная *'под json'*. И в этом
же цикле на каждой итерации переменным ***c*** присваиваются одни и те-же значения.
Как вынести за цикл такое присваивание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Ну, то есть, извратиться можно, но смысла в этом все равно не будет.

Помимо этого, никакого ручного формирования "под json" в принципе быть не должно.
Если результат запроса надо отдать в виде json, то надо использовать *штатные* средства:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT ... ");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, буду *переваривать* штатные средства.

Comment: можно уточнить? Если делать *штатными средствами*, то получаю в качестве ключей данных *на клиенте* реальные названия полей  таблицы субд. Вроде, как не очень хорошо их светить. В моем *ручном формировании* ключи - последовательность цифр, вместо названий; данные, где надо, - могу обернуть в addslashes. Такие ключи легко в цикле обработать на клиенте. Т.е., есть ли весомый профит в json_encode() и в чем беда ручной сборки json ? Спасибо.

Comment: Хотя, наверное, можно дать полям таблицы *псевдонимы* на сервере php. Но интересно, является ли ручная сборка json однозначно плохим решением и бывают ли случаи в *её* пользу?

Comment: Нет ни малейшей проблемы в том, чтобы "светить" названия полей. Для ручной сборки json нет ни одной причины, и есть ОЧЕНЬ много причин против. Не нужно доводить до момента, когда клиент начнет ругаться на неправильный формат.

Comment: Понятно, буду придерживаться *стандарта*. Сделал на php_сервере : $s = $conn->query("select 'text1' as \"1\", 'text2' as \"2\";");  $data = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); echo json_encode($data); На клиенте приходит и вижу  alert(xhr.responseText);  : [{"1":"text1","2":"text2"}]  Делаю : var x = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); И пытаюсь вынуть/посмотреть данные : alert(x['1']); // <-- undefined. Как увидеть, например, text1 или text2 подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: во-первых, вместо alert давно надо начать использовать console.log и выводить сразу x. Во-вторых, x - это объект. И втретьих, повторюсь - эти извращения с заменой имен полей никому не нужны

Comment: Если отправить от php_сервера вот так : echo '{"1":"text1","2":"text2"}';   ,то на стороне клиента приходит :   {"1":"text1","2":"text2"}   и алерт показывает нужные мне text1 и text2.   Выходит не умею работать с конструкцией [{...}]

Comment: Понятно, вот так получилось : x[0][1] и x[0][2] . Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> то получаю в качестве ключей данных на клиенте реальные названия полей таблицы субд

Псевдонимы выводимым полям можно присвоить прямо в SQL-запросе:`SELECT col1 AS "psudo1", col2 AS "pseudo2 FROM table"`

Comment: об этом я писал в комментариях выше ...